# Symfony - using a callable as factory in Dependency Injection

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, factory

Suppose I have a class `Foo` and I am provided with a `callable` which works as a factory for my class `Foo`. For example it could be something like the following (using a function here, but my question refers to a generic callable):

```
factory = function (ContainerBuilder $container) : Foo
{
    $foo = // build an instance of Foo, possibly using the $container

    return $foo;
}
```

I don't know `Symfony` very well and I don't understand how to configure the Dependency Injection component to use my callable as a factory.

I saw [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/factories.html), but it seems that I'm allowed only to used static methods of a class as factory methods, and not generic callables.

Is there a way, without creating new classes, to use a generic callable as a factory with Symfony Dependency Injection component?

Comment: Symfony container factories don't have to use static methods, dynamic ones work fine.  Having said that, I am not aware of any way to manipulate callables directly in the symfony container.  I think you will have to wrap it in a class.

Comment: The DIC is compiled, that's why it seems hard to integrate. Can you provide more information? How are the callable provided? Do you have a single file with many global variables like that?

Comment: @Federkun What kind of information do you need? I'm trying to integrate Symfony Dependency Injection in another library. Callables are not defined by me. The only thing I know is their signature, they will receive a ContainerBuilder as parameter and need to return an instance of the required service